# python postgresql select user input

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm having a problem and I think that I'm missing something very basic. I'm kind of a noob if it comes to programming but I guess I learn quick. I'm trying to make a Python script that asks for user input and then performs Postgresql SELECT. Then, the outcome of SELECT should be put into another script that uses SSH but I can't wrap my head around that SELECT query. There is a basic example of my code, if you have any tips I would appreciate greatly:

```
print('Diagnostic tool')
print('')
print('Please insert account ID:')
input()
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='psql' user='user' host='localhost' 
    password='pasword'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM exampletable WHERE acc_id = #userinput ")
    cur.fetchall()
except:
    print ("Could not establish connection to Database")
```

As shown above- how do I perform a query that uses SELECT WHERE table name is user input (acc_id)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use format function on a string.

```
id = input("Please enter your id")
# id should be passed to format. 
query = "SELECT * FROM exampletable WHERE acc_id = {} ".format(id)
try:
   conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='psql' user='user' host='localhost' 
   password='pasword'")
   cur = conn.cursor()
   cur.execute(query )
   cur.fetchall()
except:
 print ("Could not establish connection to Database")
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the input as a parameter to the query. If the input string is saved in `userInput` you can do:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM exampletable WHERE acc_id = %s", (userInput,))
```

Note: for input if your purpose is to take just the input without evaluationg as python code you should use the function `raw_input()`.

Comment: Great, I'll try that. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: My purpose is to perform query to DB that matches columns based on acc_id provided by user input and then my python script uses that output to fill ssh@xxx (where xxx is value of one column) and then uses command "arp vlanxxx (from column) userIP(from column) to check connectivity.